# multiple request before render in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

I have to render a page that will show many information for data base
For example, I will count the number of lines and the sum of certain attribute ...... and then, I will  transmit the result to ejs page.

Actually, I am doing recursive calls but I belive that there is a "better" way to do this.

```
graph.get(getURL, function(err, result1) {
        graph.get(getURL, function(err, result2) {
            graph.get(getURL, function(err, result3) {
                  res.render('index',  {res1:result1,res2:result2,res3:result3 });
            });          
        });
    });
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

Use Promises or Async library. that will reduce the callback hell.

```
promises : https://github.com/kriskowal/q
Async: https://github.com/caolan/async
```